# jQuery fine with Firefox, etc. Not working on any IE, can't find extra comma

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My website, http://kenthomes.com.au/test/gallery.php, works fine in normal browsers like FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera, but on IE6-8, two of my jQuery plugins/scripts don't work.

I think I've managed to narrow it down to this portion of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        min : 99,
        spacing : 10,
        isVertical : true,
        sticky : true,
        event : 'click'
    });

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */
    $("a.group").fancybox();    
});
```

It seems when I remove the code to do with `'kwicks'` Fancybox works fine on IE, but add it in and neither of them will work. I've looked at the `kwicks` code many times and I don't see any extra commas.

Is this a case of something else going wrong? The image scrolling header also relies on jQuery but is working fine in IE6-8.

PS: I just built a test page with all three scripts, minus the Google-analytics and pageTracker and IE8 reports no errors at all. In my `.php` pages they reported an extra error concerning `'kwicks'`. The Javascript was copied-pasted from my `.php` to this `.html` page.

http://kenthomes.com.au/test/testing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kwicks code appears broken on IE. If you load your page and click on the "Error on Page" icon in the lower left, you'll see two errors:

```
Message: '_gat' is undefined
Line: 206
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://kenthomes.com.au/test/gallery.php

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 11
Char: 252
Code: 0
URI: http://kenthomes.com.au/test/misc/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js
```

The second error is showing you that kwicks is broken, which is why your site 'works' when you remove the code that references it.

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add 'var' before 'container' in that .js file. The author forgot to do it. I didn't know initially what I was looking for when I first opened the .js file. Cheers.

Comment: @g0dspired You're welcome. Your thanks would be even stronger if you officially 'accepted' this as the valid answer. :) (Make the green checkmark show up.)

Answer (score 1):

I get the following error "_gat is undefined"

Try putting that code in your $(document).ready() function   like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.kwicks').kwicks({
        min : 99,
        spacing : 10,
        isVertical : true,
        sticky : true,
        event : 'click'
    });

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */
    $("a.group").fancybox();   

    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-3222702-4");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();  
});
```

Comment: +1 Or just move `<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` up higher in the `<head>`.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. I copied-pasted what you have there into my code and tested it, there seemed to be no difference. This might be a silly question but is there any difference between that code and the one I have? Apart from the spacing between the google-analytics and pageTracker code? I looked over it but could not see anything different. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using google analytics code and _gat is not defined. Normally we define that before setting the account.

Remove the google analytics and verify if it is working.

analytics code looks somehting like below , first fix that error

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['t1._setAccount', 'UA-9999999-1'],

 ['t1._trackPageview'],
```

Comment: I removed the Google-analytics code and the pageTracking code and they made no difference. I will definitely fix up that bit of code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 errors coming up for me in IE.

> '_gat' is undefined  gallery.php,
> line 206 character 2
>
> Object doesn't
> support this property or method
> jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js, line 11
> character 252

_gat is to do with Google Analytics not being loaded properly.

The other error would be a lot easier to see if you switched to the non-packed version of kwicks whilst you debug this issue.  Try that.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, but I just built a test page (.html) to try to narrow down the problems and all 3 scripts are working! See: http://kenthomes.com.au/test/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your help! It's all fixed up now.

See: http://kenthomes.com.au/

I've replaced the Google-analytics code, and pageTracker code to proper code that doesn't cause an error.

In the end, after hours of pulling hair out. It turned out that the problem was was that the author had forgotten to define a variable properly. It turns out that this variable had the same name as a div ID that I had ('container').

So what IE8 reported was correct, I just didn't know what I was looking for. I simply had to go into the kwick/kwick.pack.js and add 'var' in front of 'container' and problem was solved.

It seems the author disappeared so he never released an updated version with this fix, but in the comment section, people who have gone through it, have rectified it. If only I wasn't under pressure, I would probably read up and save myself a lot of stress.

See: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/06/kwicks-15-released.html (ctrl-f: container)

Thanks again for all your contributions.